# Youtube API search using php not working

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I used the below sample code for youtube video search in my page but it still shows errors like "directory not found" though i mentioned the file locations of Google_Client.php and Google_YouTubeService.php correctly

[youtube Api code sample for search](http://www.w3resource.com/API/youtube/tutorial.php)

Is there any other way for using this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [code in here](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/php/search.php).

Make sure you have the [latest library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/).

Also make sure capitalization on T of Google_YouTubeService.php